# Can't connect to SFTP and SSH (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: ssh, vps, google-compute-engine, sftp

I recently updated ubuntu to 20.04 and since then I can't connect to VPS via SSH or SFTP. I was trying to use different apps: Filezilla, WinSCP, Bitvise SSH but none of those can't connect to VPS.
I thought that I have to set external IP to static but nothing has changed. I checked my firewall
and it has default-allow-ssh rule set to all targets for 22 port. I also connect with 22 port and correct external IP and PuTTY private key. I was restarting VPS a lot of times but it's not working. Ask me for more details if needed.
[When I was trying to log in this error occures.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdGCW.png)

Comment: Please add the output of `ssh -v $remotehost`, and paste it into your question as text, not an image.

Comment: The screenshot posted is not an error, but a feature. That warning indicates how many times the instance has been booted up. This is a feature of shielded VMs: https://cloud.google.com/security/shielded-cloud/shielded-vm#integrity-monitoring-events

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as you mentioned before, your VM needs to have an external IP address, in order to send/receive external connections.

Then, you would be able to connect it using tools like putty or another tools, [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools) is the documentation about it[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance).

My recommendation is try first by shh directly on your GCP console, and then try external.

Comment: GCP Console also doesn't work. Everything worked fine, even connecting to winscp etc using external IP, before updating ubuntu to 20.04.

Comment: Are you able to access to your Ubuntu OS? for example by RDP in order to run commands like $ sudo apt install ssh, or netstat?, Also,Are you able to review if SSH or RDP ports are opened by the following link: http://port.ping.pe/YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:22 or http://port.ping.pe/YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:3389

Comment: Cannot connect through RDP and SSH, checked pinging page - every server fails to connect. When connecting through GCP I'm getting error 4003.

I don't know, maybe it's an OS error not allowing anyone to connect, like something might become corrupt.

Comment: Another suggestion that I think that could help us to debbug, is to create a new VM instance from the current disk, first you have to create a new Machine Image. Here's an inline link to [Create a Machine Image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images). And then you have to Create an instances from this machine image. Here's an inline link to [Create an instance from Machine Image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-instance-from-machine-image). Let me know about the results

Comment: Well, if you find my answer useful, or give you some light about this issue, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you

Comment: Same problem in new machine - I can't connect and error 4003 occures.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cloud Shell command prompt provided by Google Cloud platform. Cloud Shell provides command-line access to the virtual machine instance in a terminal window that opens in the Google Cloud Console.

In addition to accessing the Cloud SDK gcloud command-line tool and other utilities from the command line, you can use the cloudshell command to launch tutorials, open the Cloud Shell Editor, and download files.

Here you can find the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-the-cloud-shell-terminal).